# calculate the eigenvalue of a complex hamiltonian (graphene)

Tags: eigenvalues

I have a doubt about the calculation of the eigenvalue of the graphene Hamiltonian.

$ H = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & \Delta & \\
\Delta^{*} & 0& \\
\end{pmatrix}$

where $\Delta = \exp (-i a k_x) \left(1+2 \exp \left(\frac{1}{2} i 3 a k_x\right) \cos \left(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3} a k_y\right)\right)$ and $a=1$.

I can calculate the eigenvalues analytically:

$\lambda_{1,2} = \pm \sqrt{\Delta \Delta^{*}} = \pm\sqrt{4 \cos \left(\frac{3 \text{kx}}{2}\right) \cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} \text{ky}}{2}\right)+2 \cos \left(\sqrt{3} \text{ky}\right)+3}$

Using Mathematica I obtain,

$\eta_{1,2} =  \pm e^{-\frac{1}{4} (3 i \text{kx})} \sqrt{\left(2 \cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} \text{ky}}{2}\right)+e^{\frac{3 i \text{kx}}{2}}\right) \left(1+2 e^{\frac{3 i \text{kx}}{2}} \cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} \text{ky}}{2}\right)\right)}$

These results are different. For example, for the positive eigenvalue and for $k_x = \pi$ and $k_y = \pi$ I obtain that $\lambda = 2.08$ and $\eta = -2.08$. Also, in Mathematica there is a jump when I plot the eigenvalue between $[-\pi,\pi]$

```
a = 1;
\[CapitalDelta]  =  Exp[-I*kx*a]*(1 + 2*Exp[I*3*kx*a/2]*Cos[Sqrt[3]/2*ky*a]);
s = {{0, \[CapitalDelta]}, {Conjugate[\[CapitalDelta]], 0}};
Eigenvalues[s] // Simplify

Plot3D[E^(-((3 I kx)/4))Sqrt[(E^((3 I kx)/2) + 2 Cos[(Sqrt[3] ky)/2]) (1 + 
     2 E^((3 I kx)/2) Cos[(Sqrt[3] ky)/2])], {kx, -Pi, Pi}, {ky, -Pi, 
  Pi}]
```

How I can fix that,

Thanks

Comment: Please post the actual Mathematica code in a copy and paste-able form (InputForm) so we can paste it into a notebook.

Comment: Sure, I updated the question with the Mathematica code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for comment. Consider

```
a = 1;
\[CapitalDelta] = 
  Exp[-I*kx*a]*(1 + 2*Exp[I*3*kx*a/2]*Cos[Sqrt[3]/2*ky*a]);
s = {{0, \[CapitalDelta]}, {Conjugate[\[CapitalDelta]], 0}};

Det[s - \[Lambda]*IdentityMatrix[2]] // ComplexExpand;

charEq = Det[s - \[Lambda]*IdentityMatrix[2]] // ComplexExpand;

sols = SolveValues[charEq == 0, \[Lambda]] // FullSimplify
```

(* the output is your solution $\lambda_{1,2}$ *)

Now simple numerical check yields

```
autoEigenArg = ComplexExpand[Eigenvalues[s]];

Table[sols - autoEigenArg /. 
   Thread[{kx, ky} -> RandomReal[{-Pi/2, Pi/2}]], {20}] // Chop
```

(* all {0,0} *)

However if your increase interval

```
Table[sols - autoEigenArg /. 
   Thread[{kx, ky} -> RandomReal[{-Pi, Pi}]], {20}] // Chop
```

Then not all differences are zero. Therefore you can't fix it since the symbolic formulas indeed differ.

Your can get the same eigenvalues with

```
ss = {{0, \[CapitalDelta]}, {ComplexExpand[
     Conjugate[\[CapitalDelta]]], 0}};

autoEigenReImSS = Eigenvalues[ExpToTrig[ss]] // FullSimplify
```

(* the output is your solution $\lambda_{1,2}$ *)

**ExpToTrig[ ]** here is essential. Therefore, seems that **Eigenvalues[ ]** indeed handles both cases in a different way. Can be bug or limitation.